# mobile view image quality as blurry in product list and details page magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, media-images, gallery-image, image-quality

Image quality blurry issue in mobile view product list/details page. magento ver is 2.2.4. I found the reason for this issue.  Having 2 MB image file and product uploaded in admin side. Then i can see the image size as 200 kb only. using image adapter is graphics Gmagick . Product actual image size 1000 x 1506 px. PNG / JPEG format. For now i have uploaded high resolution image like retina images.
tried to product uploaded in admin side image size are more than 8 MB and size would be 3527 x 5290 px.After uploaded product images we can see more difference of image size and weight.[image] [I used high resolution image](https://ibb.co/dLvtvZ5)

How to avoid/control auto compression after uploaded product image? 
Anybody share the solution.

Comment: What's your setting in Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System, under "Images Upload Configuration"?

Comment: Hi there is no image upload configuration option in magento 2.2.4 @ https://ibb.co/ssxNKQL .